# How avoid form resubmission on page refresh?

Tags: wordpress, forms

I'm doing a simple feedback form on WordPress. And like many people, I encountered the problem of resending the form when refresh the browser page. I know that this problem is solved through the use of the pattern "Post/Redirect/Get". Which says that you need after processing the data $_POST, request the same page using the $_GET method. But I can not use the result of the wp_mail function for redirection.

```
if(wp_mail($email, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) {
    add_action('send_headers', 'simplemail_add_header');
}
function simplemail_add_header() {
    header("Location: http://google.com");
}
```

It just does not work.

**UPD**
Here is my full code:

```
class SimpleMailer {
    private $nonce = 'feedback_nonce';

    public function __construct() {
        add_action('phpmailer_init', array($this, 'simplemail_smtp_config'));
        add_shortcode('simplemail', array($this, 'simplemail_sendmail'));

    }


    public function simplemail_smtp_config($phpmailer) {
        $phpmailer->isSMTP();
        $phpmailer->SetFrom("admin@mail.com");
        $phpmailer->addAddress("sender@mail.com");
        $phpmailer->Host       = "ssl://smtp.mail.com";
        $phpmailer->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $phpmailer->Port       = 465;
        $phpmailer->Username   = "admin@mail.com";
        $phpmailer->Password   = "password";
        $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    }   


    public function simplemail_sendmail($shortcode_attributes) {
        global $wp;
        $result = "";
        $error = false;
        $data = array();
        $required_fields = array("feedback_name", "feedback_email", "feedback_message");

        $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
            "email" => get_bloginfo('admin_email'),
            "form_action" => home_url($wp->request),
            "form_cls" => '',
            "mail_subject" => "Feedback message from",
            "pls_name" => 'Your Name',
            "pls_email" => 'Your E-mail Address',
            "pls_message" => 'Your Message',
            "label_submit" => 'Submit',
            "error_common" => 'There was some mistake. Try again, a little later.',
            "error_empty" => 'Please fill in all the required fields.',
            "error_noemail" => 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.',
            "success" => 'Thanks for your e-mail! We\'ll get back to you as soon as we can.'
        ), $shortcode_attributes);

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
                if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                    $value = stripslashes($value);
                }
                $data[$field] = trim(strip_tags($value));
            }

            foreach ($required_fields as $required_field) {
                $value = trim($data[$required_field]);
                if(empty($value)) {
                    $error = true;
                    $result = $atts['error_empty'];
                }
            }

            if(!empty($data["feedback_blank"])) {
                $error = true;
                $result = $atts['error_empty'];
            }

            if(!is_email($data['feedback_email'])) {
                $error = true;
                $result = $atts['error_noemail'];
            }

            if(!wp_verify_nonce($data[$this->nonce],'simplemail_nonce')) {
                $error = true;
                $result = $atts['error_common'];
            }

            if ($error == false) {
                $email_subject   = $atts['mail_subject']." [".get_bloginfo('name')."]";
                $email_message   = $data['feedback_message']."\n\n";
                $headers         = "From: ".$data['feedback_name']." <".$data['feedback_email'].">\n";
                $headers        .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n";
                $headers        .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
                if(wp_mail(null, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) {
                    add_action('send_headers', array($this, 'simplemail_add_header', 10, $atts['form_action']));
                    // wp_redirect( 'http://google.com', 301 ); 
                    // exit;
                }
                $data = array();
                $result = $atts['success'];
            }
        }
        return $this->simplemail_draw_form($atts, $data, $result);
    }   


    public function simplemail_draw_form($atts, $data, $result) {
        $output = "<form action='".$atts['form_action']."' class='".$atts['form_cls']."' method='post'>".PHP_EOL.
            "<input type='text' name='feedback_name' placeholder='".$atts['pls_name']."' value='".@$data['feedback_name']."'>".PHP_EOL.
            "<input type='text' name='feedback_blank'>".PHP_EOL.
            "<input type='email' name='feedback_email' placeholder='".$atts['pls_email']."' value='".@$data['feedback_email']."'>".PHP_EOL.
            "<textarea name='feedback_message' cols='30' rows='10' placeholder='".$atts['pls_message']."'>".@$data['feedback_message']."</textarea>".PHP_EOL;

        $output .= wp_nonce_field('simplemail_nonce', $this->nonce, false);
        $output .= ($result != "") ? '<div class="feedback-info">'.$result.'</div>' : '<div class="feedback-info"></div>';
        $output .= "<button type='submit'>".$atts['label_submit']."</button>".PHP_EOL."</form>";

        return $output;
    }   

    public function simplemail_add_header($location) {
        header("Location: {$location}");
    }   


}

$simplemailer = new SimpleMailer();
```

And I get this error if I uncomment the redirect. And nothing at all, if you try to use simplemail_add_header

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/vhosts/12/151953/webspace/httpdocs/skgk.kz/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php:256) in /var/www/vhosts/12/151953/webspace/httpdocs/skgk.kz/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1216
```

Comment: Put the captcha in that form it will resolved your issue with very effectively

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a token in a hidden textbox and within the form to be submitted, the text in this text box will be the token and it need to change on every page load. Save this token in a session variable. Then add a condition at the top of the page to validate the token, if the token is different kill the loading process or display a message or whatever you feel is needed. You may also add token longevity to allow submitting of a page within certain amount of time.

The token creation, token validation and token longevity are normally a function somewhere that is called as needed and form different pages.

Edit:
If all you want is redirect the user to a different page then do:

```
if(mail succeed) {
        header('location: thankyou.html');
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks, first! Yes, I understood what you mean. Such a method has the right to exist, I think. And such a token can be implemented by means of a "nonce" mechanism. But it is not very clean, I think, with the involvement of the session. There must be a way to say to wordpress: "If the email was sent successfully, send such a header." But I do not understand enough about wordpress to do this.

Comment: I think you need to change your question a little bit. You needed to know how to redirect, however you asked how to avoid resubmission, two different problems. See updated answer above.

Comment: Yes, you are right, of course. I did not exactly ask the question, but I can not change it, unfortunately. The way to avoid resubmission the form is [known to me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), as is evident from the question. But I do not know how to implement this in the context of the WordPress environment.

In the piece of code I've just described, the same method is described, which you suggest, but relative to the wordpress environment. But it does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: I am not sure why it need to be relative to the Wordpress Enviroment, you are going away from it. Anyway, Just use wp_redirect then. See an example here: https://gist.github.com/pgooch/2307423

Comment: Thank you for your time, I am very grateful for this. I need to be inside the WordPress environment, because I have the task of implementing feedback in the form of a plugin. And no, the way with wp_redirect() also does not work with the "headers already sent" error. I can only assume that the formation of headers occurs before the wp_mail() function is triggered. But I suspect that there must be a way to interfere with the formation of headers from anywhere in the code.

Comment: Can you place here the code giving you the error and the error you are receiving? Headers already sent may be as simple as some spaces in top of the page.